# Why is my string returning "&#39;"

Tags: javascript, c#, string

I'm trying to generate some dynamic markers for a map in a webpage. Currently, I have this code which returns a string from the javascript function:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
    var franquias = _context.Franquias.ToList();
    string val = "";
    int count = 0;
    foreach (Franquia f in franquias)
    {
        count++;
        val = val + 
            @" var marker" + count + @" = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(" + f.Latitude + ", " + f.Longitude + ")," +
            @"'map': map," +
            @"'title': 'Click me'" +
            @"});";     
    }            
    MapsViewModel viewModel = new MapsViewModel();
    viewModel.Codigo = val;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

the problem is, that when the string is returned, I have this `&#39;` code appearing, which breaks my JavaScript code:

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({&#39;position&#39;: new google.maps.LatLng(-lat, -lng),&#39;map&#39;: map,&#39;title&#39;: &#39;Click me&#39;});
```

Comment: Show your view code - are you just dumping this straight out to the page instead of wrapping it in `@Html.Raw(...)`?

Comment: Please post the code where you render the JavaScript in your view.

Answer (score 5):

When writing raw strings to the page Razor will automatically HTML encode them. To prevent this, you need to use `Html.Raw`. For example, instead of this:

```
@Model.Codigo
```

Do this:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Codigo)
```

Comment: Wanted to mention ASP.NET Razor pages does this automatically to prevent attacks such as cross scripting attacks.  Tread with caution when using Html.Raw